# Token rate limiting with tokio?

Tags: rust-tokio

I would like to do something like:

```
loop {
    let ticket = tickets.get().await;
    // do some work
}
```

Semaphore doesn't do it, because the ticket should actually be used up and not be put back into the pool when done. I could have an atomic variable that is decremented together with some try-sleep-retry pattern, but I was hoping that something exists already?